# Conditionally sum based on text substrings in Google Sheets

Tags: google-sheets, google-sheets-formula

[image]

Suppose the data is text with certain consistent patterns, such as a subject in uppercase font followed by a space and a two-digit number representing time spent.

I would like to summarize all the data by a single number representing the time spent on MATH, which is 55 (minutes).

[image]

I am interested in arriving at the answer of 55 (minutes) in a single step.

I am able to isolate the number of minutes spent on MATH for each cell (possibly zero), but I do not know how to arrive at the sum of 55 minutes in a single step.

Comment: Only `MATH`? What about other subject?

Comment: It could be any subject - I chose MATH as an example. I am interested in getting the time spent on a particular subject across multiple columns/rows as shown in the example data.

Comment: Give a try to my answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You may try:

```
=index(sum(ifna(--regexextract(A:B,D1&" (\d+)"))))
```

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Give a try on the following formula-

```
=SUM(INDEX(REGEXEXTRACT(QUERY(FLATTEN(INDEX(TRIM(SPLIT(TOCOL(A:B,1),",")))),"where Col1 contains 'MATH'"), "(\d+\.?\d+)")*1))
```

[image]